# Regex: Extract two specific words

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

`1:41 Kill: 1022 2 19: <world> killed Dono da Bola by MOD_FALLING`

I need to extract all the characters before `killed` and after the 3rd. `:` that is in this case `<world>` and all characters between `by` and `killed` that is in this case `Dono da Bola`.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
:[^:]+?:[^:]+?:\s*(.+?) killed (.+?) by .+
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zR1pB0/3).

This matches `<world>` and `Dono da Bola` in your example.

Explanation:

- `:` matches `:`
- `[^:]+?` matches non-colon characters
- `:` matches `:`
- `[^:]+?` matches non-colon characters
- `:` matches `:`
- `\s*` matches whitespace
- `(.+?)` matches all characters in non-greedy fashion (`<world>`)
- `killed` matches `killed` and surrounding spaces
- `(.+?)` matches all characters in non-greedy fashion (`Dono da Bola`)
- `by .+` matches space, `by`, space, and the rest of the string.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to capture the final string, so I added parenthesis to the `(.+)`. Also thank you for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex would be,

```
^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:(.*?)killed(.*?)by.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB7tU5/1)

Group1 contains `<world>`(ie, `space<world>space`), and the group2 contains `Dono da Bola`(ie; `space**Dono da Bola**space`)